# Debugging C++ code with gdb in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I am using Eclipse gdb to debug c++ code.When step into yyparse() which is actually go thru flex and bison it happen

> Can't find a source file at "eqv_yacc.tab.c"  Locate the file or edit
>   the source lookup path to include its location.

However thr is no longer the file eqv__yacc.tab.c there is only eqv_yacc.c.the name has been changed in my makefile.How can I solve this to point to eqv_yacc.c instead of need the debugger to find eqv_yacc.tab.c?anyone face the same problem before?

```
Makefile code:

eqv_yacc.C: 
eqv_yacc.y $(YACC) $(YFLAGS) eqv_yacc.y 
sed s/yy/eqvyy/g eqv_yacc.tab.c > eqv_yacc.C 
sed s/yy/eqvyy/g eqv_yacc.tab.h > eqvy.tab.H 
$(RM) eqv_yacc.tab.h 
$(RM) eqv_yacc.tab.c
```

Comment: Is there a reason you rename the file in the Makefile? If you use e.g. `bison` then it have an option `-o` to name the output file (see the [`bison` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bison)), maybe you might want to use that instead.

Comment: You don't debug code with Eclipse (which is mostly an editor, with some graphical frontends to utilities like compilers, debuggers, ...). You debug code with `gdb`. And you should show your `Makefile` rule building `eqv_yacc.c`. Please edit your question to show that.

Comment: hi @BasileStarynkevitch
This is what i found in the makefile.the makefile was written by others.I have no idea why they change name and remove the file.

eqv_yacc.C: eqv_yacc.y
 $(YACC) $(YFLAGS) eqv_yacc.y
 sed s/yy/eqvyy/g eqv_yacc.tab.c > eqv_yacc.C
 sed s/yy/eqvyy/g eqv_yacc.tab.h > eqvy.tab.H
 $(RM) eqv_yacc.tab.h
 $(RM) eqv_yacc.tab.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `sed` commands are for replacing all instances of `yy` with `eqvyy`. You could add on to that to replace names in the source file as well:

```
sed s/yy/eqvyy/g eqv_yacc.tab.c | sed s/eqv_yacc\.tab\.c/eqv_yacc.c/g > eqv_yacc.C
```